# How to pass information between the Javascript code within a WebBrowser and Java code

Tags: java, javascript, browser, swt

I have an embedded WebBrowser where I added a LocationListener.

```
mywebBrowser.addLocationListener(new LocationListener(){  
  public void changing(LocationEvent event){
    event.getLocation()
  } 
}) ;
```

In this WebBrowser, I have a form where I can enter text.  I also have a link allows the user to navigate to other pages.

```
<form method="get" action="{$self}" name="addcommentform">
<textarea title="{$enterComment}" name="comment" class="commentarea" </textarea>
<input class="Button" type="submit" value="{$postComment}" />
</form>
```

My question is, if the user enters the text and then click on some link instead of the submit button, how can I find out what is the text entered by the user ON THE JAVA SIDE?  I want to prompt the user from the Javaside with a warning message if he / she has entered some text.

I can't find a way to pass that text entered in this textarea to my code in the java side.

I think the best way to pass the info back is through this event.getLocation() string.  But how can I append the text so the event.getLocation() can get such text?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What API or framework are you using to get a WebBrowser?

Comment: I am using Eclipse plugin framework.  I am using com.ibm.rcp.browser.service.WebBrowser;

Answer (score 0):

You can get the GET or POST parameters from your Java classes (Servlets, JSPs, Struts actions, etc.).

For example, if you want to get the GET parameter from a Servlet, you can use:

```
public class ThreeParams extends HttpServlet {
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response)
      throws ServletException, IOException {
    String comment = request.getParameter("comment");
    // Do something with the value
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the getDocument() method on the WebBrowser component?  I'm not sure if this gets updated in real-time, but it might be worth a look.